# Angular How to display unstructured data as table

Tags: angular

I'm working on Angular 5. Quite new to this so I'm not sure if it's already there or not.

In my component.ts, I have got a stream response$. The data in there is an array. Each element in the array is unknown. So data can be [ { id: 1, name: 'test'}, { id: 2, name: 'test2'} ] or [ { label: 'abc', desc: 'abc'}, { label: 'def', desc: 'def'} ]

So I only know it's an array. How can I display this data structure as a table in Angular? Can someone shed some ideas how to start?

Comment: Will the object in your array always have the same number of keys?

Comment: no. They can have any number of keys. Also I know it's a flat structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution. First, create an Angular Pipe to extract keys from a map. Then we loop through the array with ngFor and use the key.

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of data | async">
        <td *ngFor="let key of row | mapKeys">{{row[key]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So the newly created pipe is named mapKeys. Here is the code

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import _ from 'lodash';

@Pipe({name: 'mapKeys'})
export class MapKeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(map: Map<any, any>): Array<any> {
        let res = [];
        _.forEach(map, (val, key) => {
            res.push(key);
        });
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your objects always identical to each we ca do something like this:

First Read unique keys:

```
//identify unique keys in the array
    for (var key in this.arr1[0]) {
      if (this.arr1[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this.columnsArr.push(key);
      }
    }
```

Then iterate like this:

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let header of columnsArr">{{header}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of arr1">
        <td>{{data[columnsArr[0]]}}</td>
        <td>{{data[columnsArr[1]]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-key-value-table) 
You can replace arr1 and check the outcome.